# How to use a RowDetails Template with the Telerik WPF TreeListView

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, treelistview

I'm  using the Telerik TreeListView to display some hierachical data no problems.

At the end of a branch we might need to display a *list* of *related* objects.

I'd like to use the RowDetailsTemplate for this.

**My Question** - is it possible to use a RowDetails template inside a TreeListView control?

I know you can with the GridView - but not seen any examples of how it would work with a TreeListView.

TIA
J

Answer (score -2):

Seems to be possible [docs.telerik.com](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radtreelistview/features/row-details)

**UPDATE**

This piece of XAML code is acceptable:

```
            <RadTreeListView Name="example">

                <RadTreeListView.RowDetailsTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate>

                        <Views:DetailPositionView HorizontalAlignment="Left" />

                    </DataTemplate>
                </RadTreeListView.RowDetailsTemplate>

        </RadTreeListView>
```

Comment: they doco could be misleading i think.  despite the treelistview inheriting from the gridview, when iy comes to rowdetais the above does not work.  it says: **"NestedProperties are not supported: RadTreeListView.RowDetailTemplate."**

Comment: Just tested with success:                     <telerik:RadTreeListView Name="example">

                        <telerik:RadTreeListView.RowDetailsTemplate>

                            <DataTemplate>

                                <TextBlock x:Name="Test" />

                            </DataTemplate>

                        </telerik:RadTreeListView.RowDetailsTemplate>

                    </telerik:RadTreeListView>